# The complex function $\log(1+e^{iz})$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

G.H. Hardy states the following:

> The function of the complex variable $z$
>
> $$ e^{i p z} \log(1 \pm e^{iz})\frac{1}{z^{2} \pm \theta^{2}} = f(z), \
>  (-1 < p <1, \theta >0),$$ 
>        is infinitely-many valued, but can made single-valued by slitting the plane along the real axis and restricting the variable to the
>   upper half.

He then later says,

> Again, $\log(1+e^{iz})$ will be shown immediately to have an imaginary
>   part which does not numerically exceed $i \pi$ as $z$ travels along the real axis.

I don't quite understand the second statement.

The function $\log(1+e^{iz})$ can be defined by the complex integral $$\int_{0}^{z}\frac{ie^{iw}}{1+e^{iw}} \, dw + \log 2.$$

The integrand has simple poles at $(2n+1) \pi$ with residue $1$.

Each time we move around one of theses points from left to right, the imaginary part of $\log (1+e^{iz})$ decreases by $\pi$.

Why then does the imaginary part of $\log(1+e^{iz})$ remain bounded as $z$ travels along the real axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and restricting the variable to the upper half.

We consider only $z$ with $\operatorname{Im} z > 0$, and $\lvert e^{iz}\rvert < 1$ then, so $1+e^{iz}$ lies in the right half-plane, and we have a branch of $\log (1+e^{iz})$ on the upper half-plane whose imaginary part is less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ in absolute value. Thus if

> Again, $\log(1+e^{iz})$ will be shown immediately to have an imaginary part which does not exceed $i\pi$ as $z$ travels along the real axis.

refers to the boundary values of the above branch, as seems reasonable, the boundedness of the imaginary part is immediate. In the integral

$$\int_0^z \frac{ie^{iw}}{1+e^{iw}}\,dw,$$

one would then not take the Cauchy principal value to deal with the poles, but circumnavigate them by using a small semicircle in the upper half-plane, which in the limit, as the radius of the auxiliary semicircles shrinks to $0$, contributes a jump of $-\pi i \operatorname{res}\left(\frac{ie^{iw}}{1+e^{iw}}; (2n+1)\pi\right) = -\pi i$ at the poles, keeping the value within the abovementioned bounds.

For $\log (1-e^{iz})$, the situation is analogous, except that the poles are at $2n\pi$ instead of $(2n+1)\pi$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by circumnavigating the poles rather than taking the Cauchy principal value.  To me that sounds like the same thing, which would seemingly show that the imaginary part of $\log(1+e^{iz})$ is not bounded just above real axis with that choice of branch cut.  I'm sorry for being a bit dumb here.

Comment: Instead of taking (for $z = 2\pi$, as a concrete example) $$\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow 0} \left(\int_0^{\pi-\varepsilon} \frac{ie^{iw}}{1+e^{iw}}\,dw + \int_{\pi+\varepsilon}^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{iw}}{1+e^{iw}}\,dw\right),$$ we take $$\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow 0} \left(\int_0^{\pi-\varepsilon} \frac{ie^{iw}}{1+e^{iw}}\,dw + \int_0^\pi \frac{ie^{i(\pi +\varepsilon e^{i(\pi-t)})}}{1+e^{i(\pi +\varepsilon e^{i(\pi-t)})}}(-i\varepsilon e^{i(\pi-t)})\,dt + \int_{\pi+\varepsilon}^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{iw}}{1+e^{iw}}\,dw\right).$$ The former ignores the residues, the latter counts them.

Comment: I thought I was doing the latter. Each time you move around around a branch point from left to right (starting from the origin), the imaginary part of $\log(1+e^{iz})$ decreases by $\pi$.  And each time you move around a branch point from right to left (starting from the origin), the imaginary part of $\log (1+e^{iz})$ increases by $\pi$.  So it would seem to me that the imaginary part of $\log(1+e^{iz})$ doesn't remain bounded. Wouldn't the poles need to alternate in sign for the imaginary part to remain bounded?

Comment: No, on the line segment between two poles, the imaginary part of the integral increases by $\pi$ (decreases if we are on the negative half-axis going from right to left). That increase is then cancelled by the residues in the poles to keep the entire thing bounded. Rewriting the integrand to $i\frac{\cos \frac{w}{2} + i \sin \frac{w}{2}}{2\cos \frac{w}{2}}$ may make it more obvious. The imaginary part of the integrand is constant ($\frac{1}{2}$), and the residues exactly cancel the increase from the integral between two poles.

Comment: Now I understand.  Thanks.

Comment: $z \mapsto 1 + e^{iz}$ maps the upper half-plane to the disk $\lvert w-1\rvert < 1$. All branches of $\log (1+e^{iz})$ on the upper half-plane have the imaginary part between $(2k-\frac{1}{2})\pi$ and $(2k+\frac{1}{2})\pi$ for some $k$, and that $k$ is determined by the values on the imaginary axis, where $\log (1+e^{i(it)}) = \operatorname{Log} (1+e^{-t}) + 2k\pi i$, and the limit for $z\to 0$ is $\log 2 + 2k\pi i$. $k = 0$ corresponds to the principal branch of the logarithm, which usually is the most natural choice.